# Looping over two arrays in javascript simultaneously

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

```
let masterList=[{id:1,name:'Abc'},{id:2,name:'Def'},{id:3,name:'Ghi'}];
let selectedList=[2,3];
```

The desired result is to have

```
//desiredList=[{id:2,name:'Def'},{id:3,name:'Ghi'}]
```

Currently what I am doing is

```
     let parsedArray = [];
      masterList.forEach(mItem => {
            selectedList.forEach(sItem => {
                if (mItem.id === sItem) {
                    parsedArray.push(mItem);
                }
            });
        });
     desiredList=parsedArray
```

I do not find this method efficient when iterating over large arrays, is there any logic, any inbuilt javascript operators using which I can achieve the same?

Comment: how large is a large array in this case?

Comment: Do you want the code to shorter/simpler or you want to have a single loop instead of nested loops?

Comment: does the order matters?

Comment: @MaheerAli I'd say having a simpler code and having a simple loop is a win win situation. But, I'd primarily would want the code to be faster and effecient.

Comment: @NinaScholz, Yes, I'd like the order to be the same as the selectedList

Comment: @DavinTryon I'd like to have a common utility function which would do this regardless of the array size. It could be around 50, or it could be 5

Comment: 50 is not enough elements to worry about optimizing for performance. Unless you have numbers that specifically show otherwise, I'd focus on making the lookup readable and measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn the first array into an object indexed by `id` first, so you can look up the appropriate matching object in `O(1)` time, and then you can `.map` the `selectedList`:

```js
const masterList=[{id:1,name:'Abc'},{id:2,name:'Def'},{id:3,name:'Ghi'}];
const selectedList=[2,3,4];

const masterById = masterList.reduce((a, obj) => {
  a[obj.id] = obj;
  return a;
}, {});

const desiredList = selectedList.map(id => masterById[id]).filter(Boolean);
console.log(desiredList);
```

Answer (score 6):

You could take a `map` with `id` as key and the object as value and map the wanted values from the map by mapping `selectedList`.

This approach uses the order from `selectedList`.

```js
var masterList = [{ id: 1, name: 'Abc' }, { id: 2, name: 'Def' }, { id: 3, name: 'Ghi' }],
    selectedList = [2, 3],
    result = selectedList.map(Map.prototype.get, new Map(masterList.map(o => [o.id, o])));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be a simple `filter` on the `masterList`:

```
masterList.filter(item => selectedList.includes(item.id));
```

Comment: OP said: _"I do not find this method efficient when iterating over large arrays"_. I think by this OP means he wants a better solution regarding time complexity. He don't want short code I guess.

Comment: Until the OP defines what large is and what kind of timing they want, it is difficult to comment on performance. However, the OP did ask for *natvie* methods to do what they were doing.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Array `filter()` to do this.

Demo:

```js
let masterList=[{id:1,name:'Abc'},{id:2,name:'Def'},{id:3,name:'Ghi'}];
let selectedList=[2,3];

let desiredList = masterList.filter((val) => selectedList.includes(val.id));
console.log(desiredList)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can first convert `selectedList` to `Set` and then use `filter()` method array of objects.

You can use `Set.prototype.has` to check whether the `id` of the objects exists in the set or not. And this method has O(1) time-complexity. So the time-complexity of the whole algorithm will be linear.

```js
let masterList=[{id:1,name:'Abc'},{id:2,name:'Def'},{id:3,name:'Ghi'}];
let selectedList = [2,3];
let set = new Set(selectedList);

let res = masterList.filter(x => set.has(x.id));
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
let masterList=[{id:1,name:'Abc'},{id:2,name:'Def'},{id:3,name:'Ghi'}];
let selectedList=[2,3];

const result = masterList.filter(({id})=> selectedList.includes(id));

console.log(result);
```